# How to send a message from a chrome extension to another?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm making this one chrome extension that needs to communicate with another extension, and after lots of contradictory information I haven't got any results, here's the code I'm using so far:

The sending part in one of the extension's HTML (options.html)

```
console.log("sending message...");
chrome.extension.sendRequest(receivingExtensionID, {txt: "sometext"}, function (res){
      console.log("response received");
      console.log("res: " + res);
      try{
        console.log("res.txt: " + res.txt);
      }catch(e){
        console.log("ERROR: cannot print res.txt because res is undefined.");
      }
});

console.log("message sent.")
```

The receiving part in the other extension's background.html

```
chrome.extension.onRequestExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({txt: "someothertext"});
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

I don't know what else to say except the details-thing says this when you click on the error on the debugger:

```
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect
```

I have tried the same code with sendMessage and onMessageExternal and I get the same result

Please help

Comment: Did you load the second extension before the first?

Comment: Yeah, I can't believe this! I loaded them in the opposite order and it worked instantly! Thank you ñ_ñ!

Comment: Should I post an answer, so that you can accept it, or do you want to delete the (seemingly trivial) question?

Comment: Go ahead post it, other people may have the same foolish question and that way you can get recognition for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first extension (which sends the message) has to be loaded *after* the second extension (which receives the message). This is obvious: When they're loaded in the reverse order, the sender sends a message before the receiver was created.